# How to install additional python packages in Gluu

Tags: jython, gluu

There's a requirement for hashing/cryptography. While User onboarding one of the user's attributes needs to be persisted as a hash and during login the user-provided value must be checked with the hash. This is almost the same process done while using bcrypt encoders. I am trying to use hashlib. But this package is not by default in Gluu setup

```
import hashlib
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'password', b'salt', 100000)
dk.hex()
```

How can I install hashlib inside Gluu?

Answer (score 1):

Just unpack required library to ./opt/gluu/python/libs.
In my environment I just installed python package locally and copied directory with it to that folder